# Saving in CSV after using itertools

Tags: python, list, csv, python-itertools

When I run the itertools and convert this to a list I get different list like

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
```

How do I store all this this in a single csv file?
when I try to store this

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
filename = 'BinFile.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None).iloc[:, 0].values.tolist()

for a, b in itertools.product(data, data):
    data1=(a,b)
    data2=list(data1)
    print(data2)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data2)
    df.to_csv('list1.csv', index=False)
```

After i get the output when I export the csv it only show the last value

```
1
1
```

I am trying to store this like

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

Comment: I don't know about pandas but if you don't want to wipe out files, you usually append to them, or write all the data in one go.

Comment: The input data seems simple enough to write without pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you write each df (overwrites the previous value). Try this:

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for a, b in itertools.product(data, data):
    temp = [a, b]
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(temp))

dfs.to_csv('list1.csv', index=False)
```

I took the `dfs` container out of the loop, so every iteration we create a temp list, then append that list to the collection.

Outside the for loop, we write to csv the whole container data.